# c# .NET tab control

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tabcontrol

I'm using Guna2 UI. I don't know how to remove "container" or margin or whatever it is from tab control. Can anyone help me?

[image]

I looked through all properties, tried to set padding and margins to 0, but it didn't help.

Comment: have you tried https://youtu.be/ILGUQBFjZUk guide for creating tabs? It uses both `FormBorderStyle=None` and `BorderStyle=None` to eliminate borders

Comment: I know it can be done like that, but I'd rather use tab control for this project, that's why I need that problem to be solved...

Comment: Is there a reason for not wanting the tab margin. You could try a negative margin, but you may need to consider using a line of buttons formatted to look like tabs and then switch containers visible/invisible accordingly. This would emulate tabs.

Comment: Yeah there is a reason. When i nest another tabcontrol under this one, it doesn't go to the edge and it's kinda ugly. I tried negative margin, but it correts it automatically on 0...
I want to nest them like that, but without space between https://i.imgur.com/5KvIZCy.png